# cross domain request using jsonp error

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsonp

I'm writing an app and I need to access some xml data in the client side from another server(shutterfly). Because of the cross domain issue I plan on using jsonp. jQuery allows me to do this using the `$.getJSON()` method, however, I have no way to tell if the method has failed.Firefox send such an issue :

> SyntaxError: missing ; before statement ,

I think this issue cause because of the javascript content expacting from the server but we have xml as the result.

Code snippet :

```
$.getJSON("https://ws.shutterfly.com/userid/0AaOGThs0aOWsA/albumid/67b0de21da1483077512?category-term=image&oflyAppId=d484bdba28944d23285dabeee94e89bf&oflyHashMeth=SHA1&X-OPENFLY-Authorization=SFLY user-auth=005094468284|1347644121316|a47bfef9dc03697ef30a226316ce3bde0305b526&Accept-Encoding=gzip&oflyTimestamp=2012-09-15T01:36:06.190-0700&callback=?",
  {},
  function(data) {
    alert('Success');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have syntax error.
Your `getJSON()` call should be as below:

```
$.getJSON("https://ws.shutterfly.com/userid/0AaOGThs0aOWsA/albumid/67b0de21da1483077512?category-term=image&oflyAppId=d484bdba28944d23285dabeee94e89bf&oflyHashMeth=SHA1&X-OPENFLY-Authorization=SFLY user-auth=005094468284|1347644121316|a47bfef9dc03697ef30a226316ce3bde0305b526&Accept-Encoding=gzip&oflyTimestamp=2012-09-15T01:36:06.190-0700&callback=?",
  {},
  function(data) {
    alert('Success');
  }) //   <-- Remove ;
});
```